# Cross-referenceable figure numbers by section with python docx

Tags: python-2.7, python-docx

I've been using python-docx to produce large documents full of tables and figures conforming with a standard template. I have discovered how to make them cross-referenceable using https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/359 . However this labels my figures/tables starting at 1 within each section and continuing until the next section where it restarts from 1.

I would like the figure numbers to be dependent on the section number (i.e. 1st figure in 2nd section = Figure 2.1 etc.). Does anyone know if this is possible?

Currently the numbering is produced by the function:

```
def Table(paragraph):
 from docx.oxml import OxmlElement
 from docx.oxml.ns import qn
 run = run = paragraph.add_run()
 r = run._r
 fldChar = OxmlElement('w:fldChar')
 fldChar.set(qn('w:fldCharType'), 'begin')
 r.append(fldChar)
 instrText = OxmlElement('w:instrText')
 instrText.text = ' SEQ TableMain \* ARABIC \s 1 '
 print instrText
 r.append(instrText)
 fldChar = OxmlElement('w:fldChar')
 fldChar.set(qn('w:fldCharType'), 'end')
 r.append(fldChar)
```

Called by the following code which also populates the table and table title and footer

```
        table3 = document.add_table(rows=1, cols=1)
        table3.cell(0,0).text="Table "
        for paragraph in table4.cell(0,0).paragraphs:
            paragraph.style = document.styles['Caption']
            Table(paragraph)
            paragraph.add_run(text="this is the full table name")
        row_cells = table3.add_row().cells
        call_func_that_makes_actual_table(row_cells[0],...)
        row_cells = table3.add_row().cells 
        row_cells[0].text="Source: ..."
        for paragraph in row_cells[0].paragraphs:
            paragraph.style = document.styles['Source']
```

This produces a table like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaxTO.jpg)

Whereas I would like the table numbering like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFHsQ.jpg)

Comment: Please show what you've done more clearly, and how it should work.

Comment: Thanks, hopefully this is more understandable now?

Answer (score 1):

Managed to work this out myself the solution is adding a further function:

```
def section(paragraph):
 from docx.oxml import OxmlElement
 from docx.oxml.ns import qn
 run = run = paragraph.add_run()
 r = run._r
 fldChar = OxmlElement('w:fldChar')
 fldChar.set(qn('w:fldCharType'), 'begin')
 r.append(fldChar)
 instrText = OxmlElement('w:instrText')
 instrText.text = ' STYLEREF 1 \s '
 r.append(instrText)
 fldChar = OxmlElement('w:fldChar')
 fldChar.set(qn('w:fldCharType'), 'end')
 r.append(fldChar)
```

and changing the call to:

```
    for paragraph in table.cell(1,0).paragraphs:
          paragraph.style = document.styles['Caption']
          section(paragraph)
          paragraph.add_run(text=".")   
          Figure(paragraph)
          paragraph.add_run(text=": this is the full table name")
```

Comment: It is not clear what is happening here. It seems that that the table caption is part of the table itself. It is a cell content. Am I right? This isn't the way MS Word would solve this by its own. MS Word does add a regular paragraph (style "Caption") at the end of a table.

Comment: Yes, I have added the figure or table into a table containing the caption, title of table/figure and a source. Perhaps it doesn't need to be in a table, but it does work this way. Do you need help implementing it?

Comment: Thanks for your offer. I got it now. I will publish the code in some days later [here](https://codeberg.org/buhtz/buhtzology/src/branch/develop).